# Use a function inside browser.execute_script() (Selenium, Python)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, discord, local-storage

I'm trying to use a javascript code inside the console with selenium python, but I don't know how.
This is the function:

```js
function login(token) {
  setInterval(() => {
    document.body
            .appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`)
            .contentWindow.localStorage.token = `"${token}"`
  }, 50);
  setTimeout(() => {
    location.reload();
  }, 2500);
}
    
login(token);
```

I'm truing to use the function inside browser.execute_script() but I don't know how to add it.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that creates a script and returns it as a string. You can then call `driver.execute_script()` to run the script when needed.

This should work:

```
def generate_login_script(token):
    script = """
setInterval(()=>{{document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`)
.contentWindow.localStorage.token="{token}"}},50);
setTimeout(()=>{{location.reload()}},2500);
    """.format(token=token)
    return script

driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\chromedriver\94\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.youwebsite.com")

driver.execute_script(generate_login_script("testToken"))
```

I have tested this on thefamoussearchenginethatstartswithG.com and it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, where do I input the token? I tried to put it in "testToken" and the page reloaded but I wasn't logged into the account. I am using chromedriver version 94 and the token normally works fine.